# jQuery move element with effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to create a simple HTML-taskboard, some columns and some tasks, with server-side-events that will move a task from one column to another. With jQuery, removing and adding elements is easy but I want an effect (animation) to show the task is moving from column A to column B.

HTML is very simple, just a view div's:

```
<div id="colA" class="column">
    <div id="task1" class="task">Task 1</div>
</div>
<div id="colB" class="column">
     <!-- move task1 here -->
</div>
```

And a JavaScript function called by server-side-event:

```
function moveTask(taskId, fromId, toId) {
    // move #task1 from #colA to #colB with a nice animation
}
```

Using jquery-1.8.3 and jquery-1.9.2 but I'm not limited to that, could use other libraries too.

Comment: You're not going to supply any code of things you've tried?

Comment: Not so excition yet: { var task = $('#task'); task.detach(); task.appendTo('#colB'); } will do the DOM manipulation and now some animation would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something simple like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nd6dc/

```
var $bCol = $('#colB'),
    bLeft = $bCol.position().left;

var time = 0;

$('.task').each(function () {
  var _this = $(this);

  setTimeout(function () {
    _this.animate({ left: bLeft });
  }, (time));

  time = time + 200;
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean. I'll try to calculate the new position (after the move of the task node) and use the animate function with it. I will send feedback soon, thanks so far.

Comment: Yeah you basically need to impliment this into your own situation, but I calculate where the 2nd task list is (here I was assuming you are trying to animate it to the right), and just move it there. I created the interval based setTimeout just to create a cooler look of each one moving one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete function. Not perfect but fits for my needs. Thanks to mcpDESIGNS for the hint to jquery.animate().

```
function moveTask(task, toColumn) {
    var task = $(task);
    var col = $(toColumn);
    var taskPos = task.offset();
    var margin = task.css("marginTop");
    var colPos = col.offset();
    var offset = taskPos.left - colPos.left;
    var mleft;
    if (offset < 0) {
        mleft = "+=" + (offset*-1) + "px";
    } else {
        mleft = "-=" + (offset -col.width() + task.width()) + "px";
    }
    task.css({position:"absolute", top:(taskPos.top - margin), left:taskPos.left})
        .animate({left:mleft,top:"+=20px"}, 500, function() {
            // animation complete
            task.css({position:'',top:'',left:''}).appendTo(col);
        });
}
```

It calculates the offset between the task-element and the new column which is negative if the column is left to the task-element. The task-elements have no absolute position but to use animate we must set position:absolute. When the animation is complete, the callback function will remove the absolute position and append that task-element to the new column (appendTo removes the node from it's old parent)